# Error in PowerAutomate flow: 'Foreach' contains invalid expression(s)

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to create new tasks in To Do, every 2 weeks, for recurring meetings in Outlook calendar that occur between the 7th and 20th day from the task creation day. For example, if the automated process runs on March 01, it creates tasks for recurring events that fall between March 08 and March 21. And then for March 15, it creates tasks that fall between March 22 and April 04.
But, when I save the flow, I get the following error:

**The input parameter(s) of operation 'Foreach' contains invalid expression(s). Fix invalid expression(s) for the input parameter(s) of operation 'Foreach'.**

I'm completely new to using Power Automate, and I can't figure out what's wrong. I'd really appreciate your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]